# Best place for Middlewares on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware, zeitwerk

I'm currently on Rais 6 and using middlewares. I've something working but I don't like it. How should I improve it?

Currently my middlewares are here:

```rb
app/middleware/my_middleware.rb
```

And on `config/application.rb` I'm calling

```rb
require_relative '../app/middleware/my_middleware
```

Without `require_relative` it's not working. If I add them on `app` folder it's not working either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware cannot be reloaded because the middleware stack is setup during application boot and never rebuilt.

Because of that, you should tell the main autoloader to ignore the directory:

```rb
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join("app/middleware"))
```

and load the file yourself with `require` or `require_relative` just like you are doing.

There is some documentation about this use case [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#use-case-2-during-boot-load-code-that-remains-cached).

Comment: You could also place middleware somewhere  thats not autoloaded in the first place...

Comment: Yes. This boils down to "where do I like to store my code?". Some people like to have application-specific code under `app`, and put in `lib` (say) only things that are tangential/generic. If the middleware is ad-hoc for the app `app/middleware` is conceptually a good place.

Comment: Thanks! Actually my code is working in development but not in production if I add the folder `middleware` inside app. With your initializer @XavierNoria, it's working ! Nonetheless, I'm never able to switch from require_relative to require in any case. My class is never found. Is Zeitwerk loading classes after application.rb is loaded?

Comment: Oh! Let me explain. Rails autoloaders only load application code. Since `app/middleware` is ignored, files in `app/middleware` have to be loaded by Ruby, Zeitwerk does not intervene here. Like it doesn't in regular gems that do not use Zeitwerk themselves. For a `require` to work, you'd need `app/middleware` to be in `$LOAD_PATH`. Initializers have it, but in `config/application.rb` is too early. That is why you need `require_relative`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot for this explanation. That was my missing point.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. It's unfortunate that Rails doesn't have a straightforward way to load these — it's not so obvious that the main app is loaded only later.